# Check of uniform convergence of a sequence of function

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

> The given sequence of functions is
>   $$
> f_n = -\frac{e^{-x^2n^2}}{n}
> $$
>
> 1. Prove that $f_n$ tends to $0$ uniformly;
> 2. Prove that $f_n'$ tends to $0$ pointwise but not uniformly.

I have tried by using some conventional rule as Weierstrass' $M$-test, but falied to prove.

Comment: 1st one,I don't know latex properly...sorry

Comment: You should also specify the interval of uniform convergence. Is it $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for 1). The pointwise limit is $0$ and $|f_n(x)|=\frac{e^{-n^2x^2}}{n}$ attains it maximum value at $0$ (why?).

Hint for 2). Note that
$$f_n'(x)=2nxe^{-n^2x^2}.$$ 
The pointwise limit is again $0$, but note that $f'(1/n)=\frac{2}{e}$. What may we conclude?